next js 14 project structure
Help me find the answer!
I have a landing page and some other pages.
In the first layout I add a header with navigation so that it appears on all pages.
The problem is that this header is not needed when going to site.com/panel/...
How can I organize the project structure so that this header is on the main page of site.com and site.com/about and so on, but not on the panel page?


I would leverage route groups:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups
so for your purposes, I would have the following structure.
> app
|-> (landing)
  |-> layout.tsx
  |-> page.tsx
  |-> about/
  |-> login/
|->(application)
  |-> layout.tsx
  |-> panel/
|-> api/

This will allow you to define a separate layout.tsx for screens within your application vs. layout for landing pages.

The one and most recommended way is to create another layout.tsx page within where you actually want the header not to display i.e. panel(for your case). And then you can put the screen structure as you wish there.
Another way is using the react router. You can check whether the current page is site.com/panel and if its true then, don't display the header otherwise display it. But putting out react router directly in layout is not recommended method( as you need to do 'use client' to make it client component )
